# Sketch subtract weird result

Tags: sketch-app

I have some text that I converted to outlines in sketch. Now I'd like to cut out some circles from the text, so that it looks like somebody has taken a bite out of it.

When I select the circle and the text and click subtract, this creates a very odd result. Am I doing something wrong? As you can see it worked on the letter r, but not on the letter e?

[image]

Comment: i don't really know about sketch but have you tried to flatten the objects before subtracting?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know how to do this is as follows:

1. After converting the letter to outline, select the letter and hit: Layer / Path / Close Paths

[image]

2. Select the counter (inside half circle of the e) and move it on top of the outer part of the letter and fill it with white.

[image]

3. Now subtract that circle with the outer part of the letter and you're set.

[image]

If anyone knows a quicker/better/easier solution, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying those steps but still end up with my first result. I'll try some more until it works out.

Comment: Looks like I figured it out. It has something to do with the background image that's underneath.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you get odd results, when trying to combine paths.
This is because of the paths direction. Every path has a start and an end point. If two paths overlap, that have different path directions sketch might have problems to display them correct.

To fix this, you need to reverse the path direction.

```
Layers > Paths > Reverse Order
```

Now try to subtract the paths again.

Look at this article for a more detailed explanation:
[Harnessing Vector Awesomeness in Sketch](https://medium.com/sketch-app/harnessing-vector-awesomeness-in-sketch-3c9621408138)
(Under *What I Wish Someone Had Told Me*)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can also do it by moving the outlined paths and changing their combining type as above.